# Function keys for brightness (Fn+F5 and Fn+F6) do not work on my Ideapad 3 15ITL6

Tags: lenovo, brightness, acpi, function-keys, ideapad

These key combos are not being picked up as acpi events, when I run acpi_listen, I get no output, but I do get output for some of the other function keys, like the volume controls.

I have tried just about everything. I modified the grub file with different parameter combos to no avail, I added an intel file to X11, etc.

Weirdly enough, the airplane mode function key works, but it also doesn't register an acpi event!

Any help is gladly appreciated.

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Use `xev` to monitor `Fn` + `F5` event.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried this as well, but it didn't register anything.

Comment: Do you see the brightness slider/indicator on the screen when pressing the keys? ... If yes, then it's a graphics/screen driver issue.

Comment: @Raffa I don't see a slider either.